# What should be the Dilation output of a blank image if we gave a structuring elemnt with all 0 or combination of 0 and don't care

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, mathematical-morphology, image-morphology

Suppose my image data is

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

and I am giving a structuring element

```
0/-1    0     0
-1/0    0     0
 0/-1   0     0
```

What will be the output of the dilated image? The center pixel should be 1 by theory right? 
So if we apply a structuring element with only ***0 s*** and ***don't care*** in a blank image will we get a white image? 
Or such shapeless structuring elements are valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dilate an image, for each pixel you keep the maximum value in its neighborhood, and the neighborhood is defined by the structuring element.

So because you image contains only 0, the output can only be 0, whatever the structuring element.